# Remove gray tint from apps created with Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

In a project created in Titanium Appcelerator/Alloy I created a simple window with a TabGroup button. That button opens a modal window, which contains a NavigationBar.

Without specifying anything in the TSS files, a gray tint is applied to both the TabGroup and the NavigationBar(s). I'd like to remove it and make everything translucent, as it would look natively.

Moreover, you can see that the NavigationBar of the modal window is translucent during the opening animation, and then it suddenly becomes gray after the navigation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want nav buttons in header-bar area, then your only solution is to use these two properties:

1- **[Window's barColor property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-barColor)**

2- **[Window's translucent property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-translucent)**

Using first property, you can set any background color in navigation header area, and setting 2nd one to false - you can remove the transparency which will show the actual color you apply using 1st property.

Moreover, you can use **[Window's navTintColor](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-navTintColor)** to tweaks tint changes in navigation header

**+**

You can apply font & color using **[Window's titleAttributes](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-titleAttributes)** property.

```
titleAttributes : {
    color : 'white',
    font : { fontFamily : 'some-family', fontSize : 18 },
},
```

Here's a sample app I have created which shows demo of manual Modal Window animation for further fully customisation: **[Sample App for manual Modal Animation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ZdsEjK2ySITDN1VV9kS1RLcHM/view?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Actually, I don't want to set a background color; I want to remove the default gray, making it translucent...

Comment: You can't use translucency in modal windows..it's default behaviour of iOS. There are only alternate approaches for it like creating a window with a manual nav bar and adding buttons in it.
The nav-bar height is 20dp (battery area) + 44dp (header), so create a manual view of height 64dp  with transparent color and animate the whole window.

Comment: I have added a sample app's link which mimics the iOS Modal Window animation. You can use this code to modify the nav-bar as you like.